# Making a nested list from a list in Python

Tags: python

How do I make the following list:

```
nested_list = [['dave','dave'],['ian','ian'],['james','james']]
```

from:

```
list = ['dave', 'ian', 'james']
```

Comment: btw don't use `list` as a variable  name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
nested_list = [[x, x] for x in list]
```

or, if you don't mind tuples,

```
nested_list = zip(list, list)
```